# @exclude in userscript not working as expected

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have a userscript that I would like to run for a particular domain, but not for a particular page.

For example, I want to stop the script from running when the URL contains documentMode=edit:
https://blah.itglue.com/2443511/docs/8093867#documentMode=edit&version=draft

I tried this:

```
// @exclude     https://blah.itglue.com/*/docs/*#documentMode=edit
// @exclude     https://blah.itglue.com/.*/docs/.*documentMode=edit&.*
// @match        https://blah.itglue.com/*
```

However, the script still runs and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can see the URL added to exclude in Tampermonkey.

I checked this in a regex live editor and the above URL matches perfectly. I refreshed the page but the userscript is still applied....

However, if I use this, it stops the script loading on the page:

```
/(^[^:\/#\?]*:\/\/([^#\?\/]*\.)?blah\.itglue\.com(:[0-9]{1,5})?\/.*$)/
```

I don't want the script to stop working on the root domain though.....

Comment: This is a SPA so it fakes navigation via history.pushState. It's impossible to unload an already running script from the same page. You can check location.href to skip these pages in your event listeners.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean......I barely know any Javascript and just trying to modify the script. I updated my OP btw. You can see that exclude does work if you just specify the root domain. So I don't think it's to do with what you said, but rather with the structure of the regex perhaps?

Comment: No, it is precisely what I said.

Comment: All the script is doing is this. Not sure how I'm going to use this location.href... `(function () {
 'use strict';
  const next = () => 300000 + ~~(Math.random()*1.5*60*1000); // new version! - between 5mins & 6.35mins
  window.setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), next()); // new version!

  //window.setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 300000); // original working version!
})();`

Comment: Got it working now. Switched from Tampermonkey to Violentmonkey. So yeah, nothing wrong with script, just whatever regex engine that Tampermonkey (which is closed source) is using doesn't seem to work.